# Is there an alternative module for `simplegui` that can work in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: module, syntax-error, google-colaboratory, codeskulptor

I need to find an alternative to [simplegui](https://pypi.org/project/simplegui/) module that can run in both Python and Google Colaboratory. It works in CodeSkulptor platform but gives errors in the other!

Answer (score 0):

By *Google collaboratory* I guess that you mean CodeSkulptor:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/

I reimplemented SimpleGUI in Python, with Pygame library, in the library SimpleGUICS2Pygame:
https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/

With that you can run the same program both in CodeSkulptor and in standard Python 2 or 3.